# Lights flickered and we lost power to most of the house

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

I noticed the shed outside light flashing on and off then the kitchen and then the porch light, so I turned them off quickly. We lost power to most of the house except 1 bedroom.
I opened the breaker box inside the house and checked but no breakers had flipped.

So I turned them all off. I slowly turned them on one by one nothing,so when I turned the microwave off, kitchen lights worked but dim. Porch worked but dim...if I turned the microwave on we lost the kitchen and porch lights.
None of the power outlets work in the lounge or main bedroom , no airconditioners working but surge protector light is red meaning live current but not enough power.
If I turn the ac breaker off we lose kitchen lights.
It's like none of the breakers are controlling what they are supposed to control.
I checked the breaker on the outside of the house but it wasn't flipped . So I turned it off and then back on...nothing. The house is 8 years old. We did clear out some termite clay nests in the inside breaker box several months ago. it's been fine and no problems until tonight. We have lights and power outlets in the 2nd bedroom working , fridge outlet is working and lights only, no outlets in main bedroom and kitchen, rear porch.

HELP.

Comment: This will be "Closed" as a duplicate, but **please [read the linked question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/232925/help-diagnose-potential-open-neutral-80v-and-150v)**. Basically you have a partial outage - probably a "lost neutral". **Call your utility.** This is a truly serious, potentially dangerous, situation. They should be able to fix, for free, quickly. It is a rare but not unheard of problem and it is almost definitely coming from *outside* your house, in stuff that *only* the utility can work on. Don't call an electrician - they won't fix it and you'll waste time & money.

Answer (score 4):

You have a "Part no current" and it's more than likely a power company problem. One of the 120 volt lines into your meter has a problem. The remaining 120 volt line works which is why you have power in some of the house. Your AC's are probably 240 volt which means they wouldn't work either. Call your power company.

Answer (score 1):

Lost a hot feed. On a house this new, 99% likely it's a power company issue.